# Does XSLT doc-available(string) not work for absolute paths?

Tags: xslt, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm using XSLT 2 (Saxon 9.x) with Java and having the following problem ...

```
doc-available('file:///C:/Users/filename.xml')
```

returns `false`

However ...

```
unparsed-text-available('file:///C:/Users/filename.xml')
```

returns `true`

The file is a well-formed XML and exists.

If I use relative paths, then both functions return `true`.
  Also tried `file:/C:/Users/filename.xml` but with the same problem.
  I have also removed the Windows firewall, but that has no effect.

The same code works in Oxygen.

Comment: Do you run Saxon 9 from the command line? Then use the `-t` command line option to see whether that shows more details about loaded/tested files. And which Saxon version do you use, is that different from the one Oxygen uses?

Comment: Any way to find out what the version of Saxon is, from within a stylesheet? I could then run both from within Oxygen and my java app.

Comment: Sure, use `system-property('xsl:product-version')` (e.g. in a `value-of` or `sequence`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doc-available() can return false for two reasons: the file doesn't exist, or it can't be parsed as well-formed XML. You've eliminated the first possibility using unparsed-text; that leaves the second. I can't see any reason why a relative URI should work and not an absolute URI. (Well, actually I can, like the relative URI is actually fetching the file from a different location than the absolute URI.)

Essentially there are so many variables affecting the outcome that it's very hard to tell you what the cause is in your particular case.

Comment: It will be very nice to dump the entire environment from within a stylesheet. Perhaps something like "env" on linux. I wonder if thats possible. That way it will be easy to compare.

Comment: The "entire environment" is quite big - the whole of the world-wide-web!

Comment: `doc-available()` also fails, if the linked DTD in the document can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have 7 doc-available statements in an XSLT run in the Oxygen Editor version 25.1 using the Debugger mode.  The first five doc-available tests return true; the last two false.  All 7 files are in the same directory and are valid XML.  When I open the last two files in Oxygen, the debugger runs the XSLT fine: all 7 documents are found; all 7 doc-available tests return true.  When I have just the main input file open, four of the other unopened files are found, the last two are not.  Is there some arbitrary limit on how many unopened files Oxygen will find?